# How to install bcrypt on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, express, bcrypt

I want to install [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) in my Express project. I have followed the instructions provided in this [page](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/wiki/Installation-Instructions#microsoft-windows) for windows users. I just run the given command `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` and it was successfully like shown in the picture below.

[image]
But still when I run `npm i bcrypt` I get the following error:

> node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download
> node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v3.0.3/bcrypt_lib-v3.0.3-node-v64-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
> node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@3.0.3 and node@10.15.0 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
> gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python2.7", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
> ....more errors

I managed to set Python path from this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33047257/8150077). Now I get this error:

> node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download
> node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404) https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v3.0.3/bcrypt_lib-v3.0.3-node-v64-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
>
> node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@3.0.3 and node@10.15.0 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch. blowfish.cc bcrypt.cc bcrypt_node.cc win_delay_load_hook.cc

Comment: I don't know it works or not. `npm cache clean --force`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Install
[node-gyp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp)  package globally and then retry `npm i bcrypt`

```
npm i -g node-gyp
```

Comment: This fixed it for me right away!  Thank you. (this should be the accepted answer in my opinion -- the question is how to get bcrypt installed on Windows, not "what is an alternative to bcrypt on windows")

Answer (score 5):

After so much struggle of installing [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) in windows 10, I finally gave up and decided to install alternative package [bcrypt.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs) which is optimized bcrypt written in JavaScript with **zero** dependencies. Hope this will help someone who is facing similar issue.

Just use `npm i bcryptjs` instead of `npm i bcrypt`

Answer (score 1):

you are either trying to download a package which is no longer present in the GitHub of bcrypt OR the package has moved.
Either way, bcrypt is primarily a python package. Using npm, it forces you to use python 2.7 while there is a perfectly functional version of bcrypt for python 3(used it in the past).

I recommend using a node-centric package instead of bcrypt or detaching its use from npm and running it separately with python 3.

Comment: Thanks for response! But what do you mean by node centric package? Which one should I use?

Comment: There are some good suggestions in the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19822643/what-is-an-alternative-for-bcrypt-to-use-with-node)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes `npm i -g node-gyp` command not works. In my case I just run the command `npm i -g node-gyp` and tried to uninstall and install again the bycript and it works.

Delete the bcrypt

> npm uninstall bcrypt

Download bcrypt again

> npm install bcrypt

Answer (score 0):

I was try to write `npm i -g bcrypt` and then write `npm i bcrypt`. Now it's working for me!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the environment variable was a mess.

I've to clean the environment variable regarding `node-gyp`. `npm life-cycle` module was dependent on `node-gyp` and this was present in the path as `node-gyp`

Also i noticed there was multiple entry for python one is for 2.7 and another is 3.x
I kept them both and make sure npm used python 2.7

Then i installed `node-gyp` globally and finally `npm i bcrypt`

https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation